# Best order to allocate services in graph using custom comparator

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, algorithms, machine-learning, clustering

Good day!

I have a lot of graphs with different properties: structure, number of nodes & edges, etc. All of them are undirected, "weighted" (edges have width, in other words capacity). In each graph my goal is to allocate as many services as possible. Service is a triple of <start_vertice, dest_vertice, capacity>. The main difference is that the same frequency range should be allocated for each edge of the path of some service. But it's not so important for my question.

The greedy algorithm I have work as follows:

1. Sort all the services with comparator, that uses next parameters of the services: capacity, shortest path length, degree in "service shortest paths intersection graph", etc.
2. Select the minimal service w.r.t. comparator.
3. Allocate it.
4. Return to step 2.

What wondered me is that changing parameters order and priority in comparator (in-)decreased number of services allocated significantly. For example, here's results for some of them:

1. Comparator choosing the <minimal capacity, maximal degree> services allocated 541 out of 725.
2. Whereas <maximal capacity, minimal degree> -- 421 out of 725.

**Finally, my question**: how to optimally choose comparator (it's parameters, order, priority) for all the graphs I have? Optimal comparators are not the same for all of them because of the strong graphs differences.

Is it possible to train Neural Network to classify some graphs by their parameters (|E|, |V|, cliques, diameter, radius, etc) and suggest for them some comparator?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your definition of allocating a service : Choosing a path from start_vertex to end_vertex and filling all edges with capacity? Finding a flow from start_vertex to end_vertex with flow equal to the capacity? (instead of a simple path, you allow bifurcations, and the capacity can be split at the bifurcations) ? Something else? Edit : ok, seems to be a path, it was a bit hidden in your question

Comment: This problem is known as the Unsplittable Flow Problem, there seems to be some approximation results from greedy algoithms (see "A note on the greedy algorithm for the unsplittable flow problem", Petr Kolman)

Comment: @caduk thanks for your answer, but my problem is quite harder. When I allocate some service, the range of frequencies that it uses on each edge of it's path stay consistent. And different services frequency ranges on each edge of the graph can't intersect.